# Context Compat having error when met with checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I've been trying to perform a simple permission check on Android.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        alertboxGranted();
                }
```

I've been trying support 4x Android (Basically <23 API)

(Also, FYI, I have imported the required components in the Manifest and at the start of the program)

However, when I add the above ContextCompat, it comes up with error that the checkSelfPermission cannot be applied to java.lang.Strings

But isn't ContextCompat basically there to support the checkSelfPermission? I am not sure why it's coming up that error. Can anyone suggest why that error would come up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I add the above ContextCompat, it comes up with error that the checkSelfPermission cannot be applied to java.lang.Strings

Correct. You are missing [the `Context` first parameter to the method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
  private boolean canGetLocation() {
    return(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
  }
```

Comment: Oh, so the permissions. is not a context of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. So the boolean you provided me with was the correct check for permission and I should call the boolean instead of the faulty. Thanks!